# asp mvc how i can search record from data base

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want search record from the sql server data base but i can't search the record my index form  code is as follows:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Submit","Candidates",FormMethod.Post)){ %>
  Enter keyword to search
  <div id="searchBox">
   <input type= "text" name="FirstName" 
                id="FirstName" maxlength="70" onfocus="this.value=''" value=""/><br />

   <input id="search" type="submit" value="Search" />
  </div>
<% } %>
```

**mysql Repository code**

```
public class SqlCandidatesRepository:ICandidatesRepository
 {
   private Table<Candidate> candidatesTable;
   public SqlCandidatesRepository(string connectionString)
   {
     candidatesTable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Candidate>(); 
   }
   public IQueryable<Candidate> SearchCandidate(string key)
   {
     var candidate = (from p in 
                         candidatesTable 
                           where p.FirstName == key
                            select p);

     return candidate;
     }  
 }
```

**Controller code**

```
  public class CandidatesController : Controller
     {
    //
    // GET: /Products/
    private ICandidatesRepository candidatesRepository;
    public CandidatesController(ICandidatesRepository candidatesRepository)
    {


        this.candidatesRepository = candidatesRepository;
    }

public ActionResult CandidateSearch(string name)
 {
  var candidate = candidatesRepository.SearchCandidate(name);
  return View(candidate.ToList());
 }
       }
```

Exception trace :

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly. 
>   Requested URL: /Home/Submit**

Please help and give me sample code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is creating a form which will post to the action "Submit" on the "Candidates" controller.

I don't know what your controller is called but your action is called "CandidateSearch".

Change your markup to: (assuming that your page was rendered by the same controller that it is posting back to).

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("CandidateSearch")){ %>
```

OR

```
  <% using (Html.BeginForm("CandidateSearch","TheControllerName")){ %>
```

Comment: i am change markup  but i didn't get data  from the table but some exception  are occur The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[DomainModel.Entities.Candidate]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DomainModel.Entities.Candidate'.

Comment: plz any one help me and give me a example code how i can search record.